# Having two stores of an object in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following code in java

```
Object object = new Object();
mylist.add(object);
mylist2.add(object);
```

As far as I understand I have created one object in memory and both `mylist` and `mylist2` have some kind reference to this object. Is that correct?

In which case how much more memory does the program above use compared to if I had just done

```
Object object = new Object();
mylist.add(object);
```

I'm wondering because I sometimes feel it would be useful to have two **different** data structures holding the **same** information for different purposes.

Ex:
*A binary tree and a hash map such that you can easily search for objects in constant time and easily iterate through an ordered list of the objects.*

Comment: obviously more DS means more more maintenance(which too requires space, for maintaining references)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what type of list you use. If you use an `ArrayList`, then there is no overhead for each entry except the reference itself (4 bytes on a 32 bit machine, ignoring the empty space in this kind of list ;)). If you use for example a `LinkedList` then there is a wrapper object around it, which additionally holds a reference to the previous/next element in the list.

Answer (score 1):

On most VMs the size of a reference is the native pointer size (from [John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet))
So if you use a 32bit VM e.g. it will be 4 bytes.